Como puedo hacer que los archivos se puedan subir separados
Por ejemplo que hoy se sube el Layout y mañana queda el diseño, pero quiero que el layout se suba hoy y mañana ya que quede el diseño lo pueda subir y asi con los demas campos.
Asi es como tengo para subir los archivos a la tabla

solo quiero subir ese y me manda error al oprimir el boton


Al demostrar lo que se subio saldria asi, solo es un ejemploe esta imagen.

lo que ocupo es que el usuario pueda subir solo un archivo por como vaya avanzando al hacer su trabajo, no quiero que tenga que subir los 4 a la misma vez.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Subir Archivo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Subir Archivo</h2>
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php">
    <label for="designFile">Design:</label>
    <input type="file" name="designFile" id="designFile">
    <br>
    <label for="layoutFile">Layout:</label>
    <input type="file" name="layoutFile" id="layoutFile">
    <br>
    <label for="jpgFile">JPG File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="jpgFile" id="jpgFile">
    <br>
    <label for="cadFile">CAD File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="cadFile" id="cadFile">
    <br>
    <label for="measurementFile">Measurment file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="measurementFile" id="measurementFile">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Subir Archivos</button>
    </form>
   </body>
   </html>




<?php
// Configurar conexión a la base de datos MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dibujo";

// Crear conexión
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Verificar conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Manejar la subida de archivos
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Subir archivo Design
if (isset($_FILES["designFile"]) && isset($_FILES["layoutFile"]) && isset($_FILES["jpgFile"]) && isset($_FILES["cadFile"]) && isset($_FILES["measurementFile"])) {
    $designFileName = $_FILES["designFile"]["name"];
    $designTempName = $_FILES["designFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $designLocation = "design/" . $designFileName;

    $layoutFileName = $_FILES["layoutFile"]["name"];
    $layoutTempName = $_FILES["layoutFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $layoutLocation = "layouts/" . $layoutFileName;

    $jpgFileName = $_FILES["jpgFile"]["name"];
    $jpgTempName = $_FILES["jpgFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $jpgLocation = "jpgFile/" . $jpgFileName;

    $cadFileName = $_FILES["cadFile"]["name"];
    $cadTempName = $_FILES["cadFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $cadLocation = "cadFile/" . $cadFileName;

    $measurementFileName = $_FILES["measurementFile"]["name"];
    $measurementTempName = $_FILES["measurementFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $measurementLocation = "measurement/" . $measurementFileName;

    if (move_uploaded_file($designTempName, $designLocation) && move_uploaded_file($layoutTempName, $layoutLocation) && move_uploaded_file($jpgTempName, $jpgLocation) && move_uploaded_file($cadTempName, $cadLocation) && move_uploaded_file($measurementTempName, $measurementLocation) ) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO files (design_archivo, layout_archivo, jpg_archivo, cad_archivo, measurement_archivo) VALUES ('$designLocation', '$layoutLocation', '$jpgLocation', '$cadLocation', '$measurementLocation')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) !== TRUE) {
            echo "Error al guardar el archivo Design en la 
  base de datos: " . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        
        echo "Error al subir el archivo." . $conn->error;
    }
}

//

      }

      // Cerrar conexión
   $conn->close();
  ?>


Leíste lo que pides? Le entendiste? Porque no se entiende que es lo que necesitas... Lee el [tour] y [ask]

Pero si ya hiciste eso, ya esta hecho lo que pedis.. solo es un control y no forzar a que sea todo junto.. no entiendo la pregunta...

al subir solo el de diseño me manda error, tengo que sibir los 4 a la mismo vez

En tu base de datos tienes que permitir valores null en esos campos y además un nuevo campo como PK. Luego en PHP debes crear 2 funcionalidades (1) Nuevo para crear un registro (insert) y (2) Editar para ir agregando nuevos elementos a un registro ya existente (update) por esto último es que necesitas un PK

Te da error porque tu codigo pide que mandes todos los archivos. Eso me hace suponer, que este codigo no es tuyo, o no entendiste como funciona... no?

Lo primero que deberías hacer es independizar la comprobación de los archivos que se suben  y luego también la subida del fichero deseado.
Por ejemplo en la comparación if cambiar la comparación AND por OR de forma tal, que en lugar de comprobar que existan todos los archivos solo comprobaremos si se sube alguno.
if (isset($_FILES[&quot;designFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;layoutFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;jpgFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;cadFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;measurementFile&quot;]))

Luego realizar la subida independiente de cada archivo de la misma forma ya que al intentar subir todos los archivos al mismo tiempo y alguna variable está  vacía genera un error que cancela la subida de todos los elementos en la ejecución.
if (move_uploaded_file($designTempName, $designLocation) || move_uploaded_file($layoutTempName, $layoutLocation) || move_uploaded_file($jpgTempName, $jpgLocation) || move_uploaded_file($cadTempName, $cadLocation) || move_uploaded_file($measurementTempName, $measurementLocation) ) 

O de lo contrario usar múltiples comprobaciones if para move_uploaded_file(). A continuación dejo posible solución.
&lt;?php

// Manejar la subida de archivos
if ($_SERVER[&quot;REQUEST_METHOD&quot;] == &quot;POST&quot;) {

// Subir archivo Design
if (isset($_FILES[&quot;designFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;layoutFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;jpgFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;cadFile&quot;]) || isset($_FILES[&quot;measurementFile&quot;])) {
    $designFileName = $_FILES[&quot;designFile&quot;][&quot;name&quot;];
    $designTempName = $_FILES[&quot;designFile&quot;][&quot;tmp_name&quot;];
    $designLocation = &quot;design/&quot; . $designFileName;

    $layoutFileName = $_FILES[&quot;layoutFile&quot;][&quot;name&quot;];
    $layoutTempName = $_FILES[&quot;layoutFile&quot;][&quot;tmp_name&quot;];
    $layoutLocation = &quot;layouts/&quot; . $layoutFileName;

    $jpgFileName = $_FILES[&quot;jpgFile&quot;][&quot;name&quot;];
    $jpgTempName = $_FILES[&quot;jpgFile&quot;][&quot;tmp_name&quot;];
    $jpgLocation = &quot;jpgFile/&quot; . $jpgFileName;

    $cadFileName = $_FILES[&quot;cadFile&quot;][&quot;name&quot;];
    $cadTempName = $_FILES[&quot;cadFile&quot;][&quot;tmp_name&quot;];
    $cadLocation = &quot;cadFile/&quot; . $cadFileName;

    $measurementFileName = $_FILES[&quot;measurementFile&quot;][&quot;name&quot;];
    $measurementTempName = $_FILES[&quot;measurementFile&quot;][&quot;tmp_name&quot;];
    $measurementLocation = &quot;measurement/&quot; . $measurementFileName;

    if (move_uploaded_file($designTempName, $designLocation) || move_uploaded_file($layoutTempName, $layoutLocation) || move_uploaded_file($jpgTempName, $jpgLocation) || move_uploaded_file($cadTempName, $cadLocation) || move_uploaded_file($measurementTempName, $measurementLocation) ) {
        $sql = &quot;INSERT INTO files (design_archivo, layout_archivo, jpg_archivo, cad_archivo, measurement_archivo) VALUES (&#39;$designLocation&#39;, &#39;$layoutLocation&#39;, &#39;$jpgLocation&#39;, &#39;$cadLocation&#39;, &#39;$measurementLocation&#39;)&quot;;
        if ($conn-&gt;query($sql) !== TRUE) {
            echo &quot;Error al guardar el archivo Design en la 
  base de datos: &quot; . $conn-&gt;error;
        }
    } else {
        
        echo &quot;Error al subir el archivo.&quot; . $conn-&gt;error;
    }
}

//

      }

      // Cerrar conexi&#243;n
   $conn-&gt;close();
  ?&gt;


Muchas Gracias Carlos

Es de uso en la comunidad el no dar gracias en los comentarios, ya que la mejor forma para esto es marcar la respuesta como aceptada si resuelve ti problema y dar un punto a favor a la respuesta
